# How to push notifications with angular.js?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angularjs, push-notification, mean-stack

I have been building a simple application to learn angular.js. So far I hooked up all the pieces in the MEAN stack and I am able to save and retrieve data from Mongo.

The app is essentially a todo list. The user can create a project and inside the project create "cards" with "todos" which can then be moved from state to state ("backlog", "in progress", "complete", etc.)

I would like to be able to push the notifications to all the people who are connected to tell their apps that a refresh is needed to get the latest todos. In other words, let's say that user A adds a new card to project A, I would like to send a message out to all users who are currently watching project A so that their application issues a project refresh to get the latest and greatest.

Any suggestions on how to proceed? Which technology, if any, I need to add to the MEAN stack to be able to do something like this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you're on the MEAN stack, the standard recommendation in Node would be to use the [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) API.

They provide the following example of two way messaging (which would facilitate your push messages very easily):

**Client**

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

**Server**

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

It will use websockets where possible, and fallback to AJAX long polling or Flash polling in browsers where there is no websocket support.

As for integrating with Angular, here's a good blog post on [Socket.IO and Angular](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/):

> I'll be writing about how to integrate Socket.IO to add real-time
>   features to an AngularJS application. In this tutorial, I'm going to
>   walk through writing a instant messaging app.

Comment: I know, I am not supposed to use comments to thank people, but I just wanted to say thank you for taking the time to answer. :) You have opened for me a whole new world of things to learn :)

Answer (score 4):

If you're already working with Express, you should check out [express.io](http://express-io.org/).

It has a bunch of cool features like Session support and the ability to forward normal HTTP routes to realtime routes.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a module we have written for getting AngularJS push notifications working in PhoneGap / Cordava (with full instructions):
http://www.scorchsoft.com/blog/free-angularjs-cordova-push-notification-plugin/

Simply [download the example code](http://www.scorchsoft.com/public/files/AngularJS-Cordova-push-notification-plugin.zip) and install. There is also code included for setting up the pushing component in PHP.

Comment: Your code works great!  I did have to do some modifications to pushnotification.js.  1) You need an empty "[]" argument at "angular.module('pushNotify', [])" and 2) you're missing a closing ")" at "phonegapReady().then("... why not create this on Github?  Would be easier to make people use and also others to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

> Why not with HTML5 Notification API....

```
export default class NotificationService {
    /**
     * Constructor of the class.
     *
     */
    constructor() {}

    showPushNotification(title: string = '', message: string, iconPush) {
        if (window.Notification && Notification.permission !== "denied") {
            Notification.requestPermission(function(status) {
                var n = new Notification(title, {
                    body: message,
                    icon: iconPush
                });
            });
        }

    }
}
```